# Call parent function with child data in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a modal that I've placed in a separate file which looks like so (edited for brevity):

```
const DelegateModal = ({ selected, selectedFunc, visible, press}) => {

return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 50, marginBottom: 50 }}>
        <Modal
            animationType={'slide'}
            visible={visible}
            onRequestClose={() => { }}
        >
            <View style={{ marginTop: 60 }}>
                <View>
                    <Text>Please select an expiry period for the delegate token</Text>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={selected}
                        onValueChange={pickerValue => {
                           selectedFunc(pickerValue);
                        }
                        }
```

I then call it from the parent with:

```
 renderDelegateDeliveryModal() {
        if (this.state.delegateModalVisible === true) {
            return (<DelegateModal
                press={() => this.setDelegateModalVisible(false)}
                visible={this.state.setDelegateModalVisible}
                selected={this.state.delegatePicker}
                selectedFunc={() => this.changePickerValue()}
            />);
        }
    }
```

With changepickerValue() (in the parent) being:

```
changePickerValue(pickerValue){
  console.log(pickerValue);
 }
```

No matter what I do, however, the console.log in changePickerValue is always undefined. If i put a console.log in the onValueChange, pickerValue is being set, it's just not being passed to the parent.

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to read the pickerValue in the selectedFun callback. You can fix it either by

```
 renderDelegateDeliveryModal() {
        if (this.state.delegateModalVisible === true) {
            return (<DelegateModal
                press={() => this.setDelegateModalVisible(false)}
                visible={this.state.setDelegateModalVisible}
                selected={this.state.delegatePicker}
                selectedFunc={(pickerValue) => this.changePickerValue(pickerValue)}
            />);
        }
    }
```

OR

```
 renderDelegateDeliveryModal() {
        if (this.state.delegateModalVisible === true) {
            return (<DelegateModal
                press={() => this.setDelegateModalVisible(false)}
                visible={this.state.setDelegateModalVisible}
                selected={this.state.delegatePicker}
                selectedFunc={this.changePickerValue}
            />);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh that was it. Thanks so much :)